# not() does not affect descendant DIVs

Tags: css

I have a very strange behaviour of "not()" css selector.

Here my simplified code:

```
<div id="mapDiv" class="mapDiv mapDiv1">
    pippo
    <div class="gm-style">pluto</div>
</div>

<div id="mapDiv2" class="mapDiv mapDiv2">
    pippo
    <div class="gm-style">pluto</div>
</div>
```

and my css:

```
.mapDiv1,.mapDiv2
{
    width:300px;
    height:100px;
    border:solid 1px red;
}

.mapDiv div
{
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    border:solid 1px blue;
}

:not(.mapDiv1) div
{
    color:green;
}
```

a jsFiddle is provided [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7zMuP/1/).

I would think that color:green will be applied only to second box texts, due to not() selector.... instead it is applied to both.

Can you explain me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understandings, :not() is a negation pseudo-class.

Which means, first you select a bunch of elements and then remove elements from the selected bunch using negation pseudo-class.

Hence it should be prefixed by a selector.

If you change your css to :

```
div:not(.mapDiv1)
{
 color:green;
}
```

This will select all the divs except the divs with class '.mapDiv1'

And if you change the code to:

```
div:not(.mapDiv1) div
{
color:green;
}
```

This will select all the divs within a parent div except for those parent divs with class '.mapDiv1'.

[More Reference Here](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/selectors/pseudo-classes/%3anot)

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your code as

```
div:not(.mapDiv1)
{
 color:green;
}
```

I updated your fiddle as [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zMuP/3/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
div:not(.mapDiv1) {
   color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/7zMuP/4/)**</kbd>

```
div:not(.mapDiv1) div {
    color:green;
}
```

For more on it [read](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/)